# iOS must put extra 20px for margin to align up with root view when using autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

For instance I have a background image for the whole view. I have to give the leading and trailing space to super view to -20 if I want it to align up with edge of the screen exactly. Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align to edge of the screen exactly you can uncheck the 'relative to margin' of the superview in the inspector and make constant value as 0.

[image: Unchecked Relative to margin]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just to be clear that I only need to uncheck "relative to margin" on Superview,  right? "relative to margin" on subView doesn't seem taking effect while it does work on super view.

Comment: @user744641 Yes it is relative margin of the superview. Updated image.